# Angular remove table row on submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im new to angular and I was trying to remove some elements from table on submit..

```
<tr ng-repeat="val in values ">
    <td ng-bind="$index"></td>
    <td ng-bind="val.rec">ED1500322</td>
    <td>working</td>
    <td ng-bind="val.result">I am going to School</td>
    <td>
      <div class="radio">
        <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="yes" type="radio" ng-change="log(val)">
        <label for="opt1">yes</label>
        <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="no" type="radio" ng-change="log(val)">
        <label for="opt10">no</label>
      </div>
    </td> 
  </tr>
```

All the data obtained using ng-repeat and Im not sure of remove data which is obtained dynamically

I wanted to remove row if the toggle button is clicked..(to show there was some changes done)

Plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/kNJUbUBENxBc38rBg3GK?p=preview

Any help in removing data dynamically would be helpful..Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your criteria for removing the data?

Comment: criteria would be when there is any change on the toggle button

Comment: Which data do you want to remove ?

Comment: So, those rows which have the radio button value of `no` should be removed? Upon clicking the `getResult` button?

Comment: If there is any change done on toggle button, then it should be removed

Answer (score 1):

Set a value on button-click like this:

`<button ng-click=getResult();hideme=true>getResult</button>`

and then use ng-hide on the table row where val.iscorrect is not true

```
  <tr ng-repeat="val in values" ng-hide="hideme && val.iscorrect!='yes'">
    <td ng-bind="$index"></td>
    <td ng-bind="val.rec">ED1500322</td>
    <td>working</td>
    <td ng-bind="val.result">I am going to School</td>
    <td>
      <div class="radio">
        <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="yes" type="radio" ng-change="log(val)">
        <label for="opt1">yes</label>
        <input ng-model="val.iscorrect" value="no" type="radio" ng-change="log(val)">
        <label for="opt10">no</label>
      </div>
    </td> 
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, we have to store the index of all the items that the user wants to remove from the `$scope.valueToRemove` array.

And when the user submit his request we have to remove all the items. In order to do that we have to retrieve all the index (of the item to delete) from the `$scope.valueToRemove` array. And finally, we can call the `splice()` function (to remove the item from the array) with the corresponding index.

Below an illustration of the code.

http://plnkr.co/edit/Qqce3N8LRJdoDwGMDsrd?p=preview

Comment: @JeanMel...I wanted to remove when I click on submit